# Running nginx on Alpine

Tags: php, docker, nginx, dockerfile

I would like to run nginx and php-fpm on container start, however I can't seem to do that. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

EXPOSE 9080 8000
EXPOSE 9088 80

WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . .

RUN apk add nginx composer php7-fpm && \
    composer install --no-progress && \
    mkdir -p /etc/nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled /run/nginx && \
    ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf && \
    cp nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Container comes up and running, however when I run `ps aux` nginx is nowhere to be seen until I run `nginx` command (configuration is okay, `nginx -t` returns okay, and running it through open container does start the service).

I've tried to chain `RUN php-fpm7 && nginx` but that does nothing.

Also using entrypoint like `ENTRYPOINT ["nginx"]` did nothing for me.

How can I make sure those processes are running upon creating the container?

Comment: It is a part of docker best practices - the one container is a one process. So typically you should create one container for `fpm` and another one for `nginx`. Here is a [doc article about](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

Comment: I would recommend to check the Dockerfile of lslio/nginx-php-fpm or richarvey/nginx-php-fpm. It runs as you expected. There Dockerfile may help you figure out your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add a script and use it in your `CMD`:

script :

```
#!/bin/bash
service nginx start
php-fpm7
```

add the script to your `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY /PATH/TO/script.sh /path/in/container/script.sh
RUN chmod +x /path/in/container/script.sh
CMD ["/path/in/container/script.sh"]
```

Comment: I actually used entrypoint for it `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/start.sh"]`, but it's basically it. Thanks

Comment: @Norgul Can you share your "project"?

Comment: @projetmbc I can't, it's proprietary :)

Comment: @Norgul I am damned... :-)

Comment: @projetmbc I think the only thing you might be concerned though is that I abandoned this approach. I used `nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.20-alpine` image instead of a stock Alpine one.

Comment: @Norgul Thanks for sharing. I will pay with this.

Answer (score 9):

running 2 processes in the same container is not a docker best practice, but i assume it is the correct approach for your specific use-case. luckily [docker has a solution for you.](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/):

use a management tool - [**supervisord**](http://supervisord.org/).

supervisord is designed for orchestrating multiple processes, and i consider it better than a shell script because its offering you the management and logging abilities. create a `supervisord.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
childlogdir=/tmp
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid

[program:php-fpm]
command=php-fpm7 -F
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=false
startretries=0
```

then install & copy it to your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apk add supervisor
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/
```

now your entrypoint should be:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Comment: This should be the answer for many other questions I read misleading to a failing **entrypoint.sh**.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are awesome, but As mentioned by @Efrat supervisorsd is more suitable for such cases.

One thing that I hate about copying thing during Docker build process, Dockerfile should be independent for copying thing I believe. It should be Dockerfile only that will build the Docker image, not other stuff they need to be copied. Just Extending @Efrat answer. Here you go with all configuration inside Dockerfile.

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN apk add nginx composer php7-fpm supervisor && \
    mkdir -p /etc/nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled /run/nginx && \
    ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf && \
    # cp nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    mkdir -p /etc/supervisord.d/

#supervisord basic config file    
    RUN echo  $'[supervisord] \n\
[unix_http_server] \n\
file = /tmp/supervisor.sock \n\
chmod = 0777 \n\
chown= nobody:nogroup \n\
[supervisord] \n\
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log \n\
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB \n\
logfile_backups=10 \n\
loglevel = info \n\ 
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid \n\
nodaemon = true \n\
umask = 022 \n\
identifier = supervisor \n\
[supervisorctl] \n\
serverurl = unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock \n\
[rpcinterface:supervisor] \n\
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface \n\
[include] \n\
files = /etc/supervisord.d/*.conf' >> /etc/supervisord.conf 

# nginx supervisord Config
    RUN echo $'[supervisord] \n\
nodaemon=true \n\
[program:nginx] \n\
command= /usr/sbin/nginx -g \'daemon off;\' \n\
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1 \n\
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0MB \n\
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0 \n\
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2 \n\
redirect_stderr=true \n\
autorestart=false \n\
startretries=0 \n\
exitcodes=0 ' >> /etc/supervisord.d/nginx.conf
# php-fpm7
RUN echo $'[supervisord] \n\
nodaemon=true \n\
[program:php-fpm] \n\
command= /usr/sbin/php-fpm7  -F \n\
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1 \n\
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0MB \n\
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0 \n\
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2 \n\
redirect_stderr=true \n\
autorestart=false \n\
startretries=0 \n\
exitcodes=0 ' >> /etc/supervisord.d/php-fpm.conf

EXPOSE 9080 8000 9088 80

ENTRYPOINT ["supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```