# How to run two commands on Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, nginx, gulp, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have to execute two commands on the docker file, but both these commands are attached to the terminal and block the execution from the next.

dockerfile:

```
FROM sinet/nginx-node:latest

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN git clone https://name:pass@bitbucket.org/joaocromg/front-web-alferes.git
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/front-web-alferes

RUN npm install 
    
RUN npm install bower -g 
RUN npm install gulp -g 
RUN bower install --allow-root 
    
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN nginx -g 'daemon off;' & # command 1 blocking
 
CMD ["gulp watch-dev"] # command 2 not executed
```

Someone know how can I solve this?

Comment: Try to concatinate them with a &&

Comment: I tried but not work. :\

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running nginx on Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946225/running-nginx-on-alpine)

Comment: The usual answer to this question is “in two separate containers”; there’s a standard `nginx` image that can help you run that part.

Comment: @DavidMaze i know the standard is separate in two containers, but in my case doesnt make sense (i dont develop this system, i'm just trying use container). because "gulp watch-dev" is just to manager static file and is not a different service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try supervisord in this case. http://supervisord.org/

Edit: Here is an dockerized example of httpd and ssh daemon: https://riptutorial.com/docker/example/14132/dockerfile-plus-supervisord-conf

Answer (score 15):

Try creating a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
nginx -g 'daemon off;' & 
gulp watch-dev
```

And then execute it in your CMD:

```
CMD /bin/my-script.sh
```

Also, notice your last line would not have worked:

```
CMD ["gulp watch-dev"]
```

It needed to be either:

```
CMD gulp watch-dev
```

or:

```
CMD ["gulp", "watch-dev"]
```

Also, notice that `RUN` is for executing a command that will change your image state (like `RUN apt install curl`), not for executing a program that needs to be running when you run your container. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that `RUN nginx -g 'daemon off;'` is intentionally starting nginx in the foreground, which is blocking your second command. This command is intended to start docker containers with this as the foreground process. Running `RUN nginx` will start nginx, create the master and child nodes and (hopefully) exit with a zero status code. Although as mentioned above, this is not the intended use of run, so a bash script would work best in this case.